# Subtract a value from a running series

Tags: excel, vba

I have a running list of numbers by month and I need to subtract a value from the first number, then if the answer is negative, subtract the remaining value from the second number, so on and so forth until the value that I am subtracting is consumed.

Example:

```
March   April   May     June

15         95    85      60
```

and the value I need to subtract is 200.

I need a formula/ macro that results in:

```
March   April   May     June

 0       0       0       55
```

I'm working in Excel, so a formula or VBA macro would be what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If your values are in A2:D2 and `200` in F2, please try:

```
=IF(SUM($A2:A2)<=$F2,0,SUM($A2:A2)-$F2)
```

in A4 copied across to D4.